# Как вернуть список без удаленного элемента?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, удаление

Предположим, я получаю некий список и должен удалить из него заданный элемент:

```
lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']

def func(lst, what_to_remove):
    pass
```

Я хочу, чтобы функция состояла из одной строки и пытаюсь сделать так:

```
lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']

def func(lst, what_to_remove):
    return lst.remove(what_to_remove)

print(func(lst, 'bird'))
```

И, естественно, ничего не получается (потому что `remove()` ничего не возвращает):

Возможно ли удалить элемент из списка и вернуть этот список одной строкой?

Comment: `remove` уже является такой функцией. `lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']`

`lst.remove('bird')`

`print(lst)` выведет `['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bear']`

Comment: Во-первых, показанный вами код не выдаёт такую ошибку. Во-вторых, непонятно, что вы в принципе пытаетесь сделать и зачем что-то куда-то возвращать

Comment: @andreymal, я забыл добавить `return`. Теперь добавил.

Comment: @Глеб но ошибка не появилась и понятнее не стало

Comment: @Acinit, мне нужно не просто удалить элемент, а и удалить, и вернуть одной строкой. Такое очень часто бывает при конструировании однострочников.

Comment: Рекомендую избавляться от маниакального желания лепить однострочники, они затрудняют чтение и сопровождение кода

Comment: @andreymal, разумеется, просто я люблю этим на досуге заниматься) Когда нужно что-то серьезное написать, я, конечно же, пишу ясный код.

Comment: @Глеб это что, гольф??? :0

Comment: @Глеб добавил вам еще пару решений в свой ответ

Comment: @Acinit, частично гольф) Я просто увидел похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090828/remove-an-element-from-list-and-return-the-result) на английском сайте и решил перевести, когда-то сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Comment: @Глеб вообще есть [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580337/to-remove-an-element-and-assign-the-list-in-one-line) очевиднее, который стоило бы перевести

Comment: @Acinit, хм, не видел. Поисковик его не выдавал, да и рейтинг у него 1 (а у того аж 3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы так хотите обернуть `remove` в функцию, задавая в качестве параметров список и параметр который вы хотите удалять, исполняйте в функции сначала `remove` и потом уже возвращайте список

```
lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']

def func(lst, what_to_remove):
    lst.remove(what_to_remove)
    return lst

print(func(lst,'bird'))
```

Вывод:

```
['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bear']
```

---

UPD

А если хотите одной строчкой в функции, то лучше пересоздайте лист без этого элемента

```
lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']

def func(lst, what_to_remove):
    return [item for item in lst if item != what_to_remove]

print(func(lst,'bird'))
```

---

UPD2

Можно вот так

```
import copy

lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']

def func(lst, what_to_remove):
    return lst.remove(what_to_remove) or copy.copy(lst)

print(func(lst,'bird'))
```

---

UPD3

И вот так тоже можно

```
lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']

def func(lst, what_to_remove):
    return (lst.remove(what_to_remove),lst)[1]

print(func(lst,'bird'))
```

---

Пояснение:

Последние два метода работают на основе того, что мы сначала используем `remove`, а уже потом стараемся вернуть наш `lst`

---

UPD4

По аналогии можно и так:

```
lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']

def func(lst, what_to_remove):
    return lst.remove(what_to_remove) or lst

print(func(lst,'bird'))
```

Comment: Спасибо за решения, принял ответ.

Comment: В реальных однострочниках, конечно, чаще всего все-таки пользуются `...if i != ...`. Но остальные решения тоже интересны.

Comment: вот только генератор с `!=` и любой ваш способ через `remove` дадут разный результат для списков с неуникальными элементами

Answer (score 2):

Если очень надо в одну строку, вот ещё один вариант. Используйте преобразование во множество, а затем обратно в список:

```
lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']

def func(lst, what_to_remove):
    return list(set(lst)^{what_to_remove})

print(func(lst,'bird'))
```

Этой строчкой мы выделяем *оригинальные* элементы множества из списка `lst` и множества с одним элементом `what_to_remove` (то есть выделится множество из списка `lst` без элемента `what_to_remove`), а затем преобразуем получившееся множество обратно в список.

UPD: можно сделать проверку на присутствие элемента в списке:

```
lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'bird', 'bear']

def func(lst, what_to_remove):
    return f'{list(set(lst)^{what_to_remove})}' if what_to_remove in lst else f'Ошибка: элемент {what_to_remove} отсутствует в списке.'

print(func(lst,'beer'))
```

Вывод:

```
Ошибка: элемент beer отсутствует в списке.
```

Comment: Хм, интересный способ, не приходило в голову использовать множества. Правда, думаю, это очень медленно, но идея интересная.

Comment: Да, однако иногда это решение выгоднее, чем стандартный метод `.remove()`